# How to update relationships in ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following two models:

```
App.Domain = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    user: attr('string'),
    domain: DS.belongsTo('App.Domain')
});
```

The `Domain` is loaded in the `User` record embeded:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.User', {
    domain: { embedded: 'load' }
});
```

If I get the JSON data, ember-data will interpret that correctly.

```
GET /users

{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "domain_id": 1,
            "user": "test",
            "domain": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "example.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My domains looks like this:

```
GET /domains

{
    "domains": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "example.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "example.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my question:

If I update the `domain` in a `user` record the `domain_id` foreignKey will not be updated.
If I try to commit this dirty record, ember will sending the old `domain_id` to the server. What is wrong in my code? Can I not update the `belongsTo` field for updating the `foreignKey` in this way?

```
>>var user = App.User.find(1);
>>user.get('domain.id')
1
>>var newDomain = App.Domain.find(2);
>>newDomain.get('id')
2
>>user.set('domain', newDomain)
>>user.get('isDirty')
true
>>user.get('domain.id')
2
>>user.get('domain_id')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to commit first for the domain_id to be updated.